# Reset spawn chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can you reset the location of your spawn chunks in Minecraft while still allowing block updates to be possible?

**Reason**:
I set my worldspawn to a different location from the original spawn point causing the spawn chunks to move.  This means I no longer have block updates.  This makes so I can have no command blocks constantly running and updating in my world for better creations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in my research there is no way to move the worldspawn back to where it first was unless you took note of the cords. Secondly if you want to move the worldspawn you can do so with `/setworldspawn`. When ever you set the worldspawn to a location the spawn chunks will be moved with it. Judging by your answer you want the spawn chunks to load command blocks, so all you need to do is go to the command blocks and set the world spawn. In the event that you accidentally did `/spawnpoint` (this will set your spawnpoint and not the world spawn point) to remove your spawn point you can sleep in a bed, then destroy it.

Just a note the spawn chunks will only be loaded if someone is in the overworld. (this is applies to single player and I have no idea if the rule is the same on a server.)

If you want to read up more stuff on the spawn chunks you can do so [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk)

Comment: Technically the spawn chunks are still loaded even if no players are in the overworld. But after 15 seconds of no players in the overworld, entities and tile entities will no longer be sent update ticks. Not all tile entities rely on this though; for example, command blocks will still continue to function. I have a list [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/redstone/comments/49ub8z/will_this_actually_work/d0vuare) of what will and won't be ticked after the 15 seconds.